# Center-Aligned word document style input tag

Tags: html, css, reactjs, input, bootstrap-4

What I would like to see:

A Center-Alignment of text, starting from the top of the input. Words break after hitting the internal padding (Imagine any document creation software, e.g. Google Docs, and how it is expected to work with center alignment active).

What I have currently:

Text is dead center of the input, when it should be centered horizontally while staying at the top. If I continue creating text it trails off to the right instead of breaking.

basic html example

```
<div class="text-contain">
<input type="text" class="textArea" 
  value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed 
  do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut 
  enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi 
  ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
  reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
  pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in 
  culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."/>
</div>
```

And Css:

```
.textArea {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  word-break: break-word;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 10px;
  min-height: 40vh;
  width: 66vw;
}
```

Here's the codepen `https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kxyqod`

**If there needs to be JS for this approach**, I'm using React to handle this code, so I would appreciate the 'react way' answer if it comes to it.

**If you have a css solution** it would be cool if I could keep using vw.

I am also using **Bootstrap 4** if anything comes to mind with that.

I looked for an answer for this specific question, but I cant seem to find anything related to making inputs look like center aligned word documents with word breaks on internal padding.

If I need to make any edits to this question, please let me know! I'm new at asking questions on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why didn't you just use `<textarea>` instead and paste your css on it? `<textarea>` is the element designed to handle multiple lines.

**pen**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mGqByr

Comment: Basically textarea was what I was looking for. Funny enough, I was using it at first and for some reason it wasn't working to my favor so I switched it out. I put it back in and with slight adjustment it worked. I'm surprised I have not internalized that important difference between the two until now. Thanks a Million.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to use textarea dom object, this will create a box text that specify that you want, i.e

```
<textarea name="anyname" form="insertformname">Your text</textarea>
```

whatever if this is not helpful, maybe you could use a max length attribute in your input to prevent to type more than you want to allow.

```
<input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="10">
```

Comment: Great answer, Thanks for the maxlength tip!